# Fix alignment in css

Tags: html, css, web

I was working on a project for my college using Bootstrap CSS and I am stuck with fixing some alignment issues. What I wanted to achieve is align logo to the left(acquiring 35% of width) and aligning social plugin and Sign Up & Sign In button to the right(acquiring the leftover space i.e. 65%).

The issue I am facing right now is everything is aligned vertically! What I've coded so far is mentioned below. Would appreciate if someone fixes bug in my code rather than coming up with a new one.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="topBar">
        <div class="topLeft">Logo</div>
        <div class="topRight">
            <div class="socialPlugin">f t g</div>
            <div class="signUpIn">Sign Up/In</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#topBar {
    width: 100%;
}
#topBar .topLeft {
    width: 35%;
}
#topBar .topRight {
    width: 65%;
}
#topBar .topRight .socialPlugin {
    float: left;
}
#topBar. topRighht .signUpIn {
    float: right;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qv3Lbqtd/)**

Thank you

Comment: Why are you bothering with Bootstrap if you're not going to use the grid and the other layout components provided?

Comment: Are you actually asking someone to do all the Bootstrap integration into your code for you... ? Have you read Bootstrap's documentation for the correct classes? - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Comment: I am using bootstrap because I want everything to be responsive @isherwood

Comment: But you're not using Bootstrap... you have no bootstrap classes in your code.

Comment: Here's a demo of how this might go using Bootstrap as intended. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qv3Lbqtd/3/

Comment: No, I am not asking someone to do stuff for me. I just want someone to help me to sort out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I didnt mention it here but I am actually importing it @Lee

Comment: What's wrong with your code is that you're assigning custom widths to things. That's rarely the right approach with a robust, responsive library at your disposal.

Comment: Just importing it, won't do anything. You need to add classes and stuff into your code to be able to use it.

Comment: @Lee I imported bootstrap and I used the container class from it. Which perhaps wraps up everything.

Comment: Read the Bootstrap documentation...You're missing out alot. Bootstrap has column widths all built into it, so the idea is you don't use your own CSS rules, but instead you add classes to elements of your HTML code. Take a look at the URL I gave, and the grid layout.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the fact that Bootstrap is not being used most of what you want can be solved by correctly applying `float` and clearing floats as necessary.

```css
#topBar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* quick clearfix */
}
#topBar .topLeft {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
}
#topBar .topRight {
  width: 65%;
  background: #bada55;
  float: left;
}
#topBar .topRight .socialPlugin {
  float: left;
  width:50%;
}
#topBar. topRighht .signUpIn {
  float: right;
    width:50%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="topBar">
    <div class="topLeft">Logo</div>
    <div class="topRight">
      <div class="socialPlugin">f t g</div>
      <div class="signUpIn">Sign Up/In</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D That helped! How can this be a bad question? @ isherwood

Comment: It's a 'bad' question because you have a misleading title. The question has *nothing* to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: @EricCartman there's nothing in your code or on the answer's code that relates to Bootstrap. If you edit your question without referencing Bootstrap, it will become better just by doing that... Or you can also ask how to use properly the Bootstrap classes in order to achieve the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for the most part you've just got a typo in the last selector of your css:

Change `#topBar. topRighht .signUpIn` to `#topBar .topRight .signUpIn`, which I did to [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv3Lbqtd/5/).